Import json file on python
I try to import a json file on python with :
with open('C:/Users/angel/message.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

I have the error :
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 with open('C:/Users/angel/message.json', 'r') as file:
      2     data = json.load(file)

File /lib/python3.12/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:324, in _modified_open(file, *args, **kwargs)
    317 if file in {0, 1, 2}:
    318     raise ValueError(
    319         f"IPython won't let you open fd={file} by default "
    320         "as it is likely to crash IPython. If you know what you are doing, "
    321         "you can use builtins' open."
    322     )
--> 324 return io_open(file, *args, **kwargs)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 44] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/angel/message.json'

I've tried putting my json file in different folders, and changing the “/” but I still get the error.
Can you help please ? I don't understand the problem

That's a Windows pathname. What operating system are you using? The filenames in the traceback look like Unix. Unix doesn't have driver letters like C:

use os for declaring the path of json file
example
import os
path = os.path.join("C:","Users","angel","message.json")

you can also use os.getcwd() to get current path your code is running
and just use path in open like this
with open(path, 'r') as file:

you should use os.path because provides functions for manipulating filesystem paths in a way that is compatible with different operating systems also there is another library you can use
pathlib
if this does not solve your problem, make sure that you are using the correct address and that the file exists
and some times there is invisible character in your file name so to if you are not sure about that just rename your file and let me know if this solved your problem

While this is a good idea, I don't see why it would fix the problem.

answer updated!

How is the subprocess library relevant to this? That's for running external programs, it has nothing to do with pathnames.

You are right, I confused pathlib with subprocess

Nonetheless, the problem is almost certainly that the path is wrong. Changing the way they create it won't solve that problem.

look at the other answer comments he/she says its worded

if this is not helping this question need more detail

@Barmar i'm wondering why you give me down voit ?

I didn't give you a downvote.

What happens if you put the folder in the same directory as the python script and try to open it just as 'message.json'?

Why would this make a difference? Windows allows paths to use either type of slash.

Thank you, I put it in the same directory as the python script and it works :)
